# Is there a way to convert an object with Partial types to an object without Partial types?

Tags: typescript

Given a type:

```
type Person = {
  name: {
    first: string,
    last: string;
  },
  age: number
};
```

and a version of that type where the object and nested object are marked `Partial`:

```
type PartialPerson = Partial<{
  name: Partial<{
    first: string,
    last: string;
  }>,
  age: number
}>;
```

If I have an instance of `PartialPerson` that has all properties populated:

```
const completePartialPerson: PartialPerson =  {
  name: {
    first: 'joe',
    last: 'bloggs',
  },
  age: 45
};
```

Is there a way I can have Typescript treat it as the normal `Person` object - ie: it would be accepted as a parameter to this function:

```
function addPerson(person: Person){}

addPerson(completePartialPerson);
```

This results in an error:

```
Argument of type 'Partial<{ name: Partial<{ first: string; last: string; }>; age: number; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Person'.
  Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
    Type 'Partial<{ first: string; last: string; }>' is not assignable to type '{ first: string; last: string; }'.
      Property 'first' is optional in type 'Partial<{ first: string; last: string; }>' but required in type '{ first: string; last: string; }'.(2345)
```

I can use `as`:

```
addPerson(completePartialPerson as Person);
```

but this comes at the cost of type safety - if I change the name of `Person.name` to `name2` there is no error.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-2po9vw?file=index.ts

Comment: *"If I have an instance of PartialPerson that has all properties populated"* Why is it given the type `PartialPerson` if it's actually a `Person`?

Comment: Which version of ts are you using? Are you able to use `satisfies` operator?

Will [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wO5Bdm) work for you? If yes, I'll write answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the types are applied by a library outside of my control

Comment: @wonderflame using TS 4.6, however aside from that it looks like I can't use your approach as `completePartialPerson` is defined in an external library where it is given the type `PartialPerson`

Comment: Then it seems that the custom type guard will be the only option that I can think of

Answer (score 0):

If you want a runtime-checked type assertion, the usual answer is to use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) or a [type assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions). For instance, here's a type predicate checking whether a `PartialPerson` is a `Person`:

```typescript
function isPerson(p: PartialPerson): p is Person {
    if ("name" in p && "age" in p) {
        if ("first" in p.name! && "last" in p.name) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can use that like this:

```typescript
if (isPerson(completePartialPerson)) {
    // Here, the type of `completePartialPerson` has been narrowed to `Person`
    // ...
}
```

An assertion function takes it a step further and throws an error if it's not valid. Here's one building on the above:

```typescript
function assertIsPerson(p: PartialPerson): asserts p is Person {
    if (!isPerson(p)) {
        throw new Error("Assertion failure, incomplete person object provided");
    }
}
```

You'd use that like this:

```typescript
assertIsPerson(completePartialPerson);
// Here, the type of `completePartialPerson` has been narrowed to `Person`
// ...
```

[Playground link for all of the above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBQKlQEMBbCALh30NoDMBLJYKxYeB1AcwG4baCAG2JtW7Tr35QAvn1rEulIgFdSAIwR9ZuUJFjF4wBsUFwkaTPsPHBAHjy0S5KjANGT9qfSaiobDtxyAkIiLH7igVLSAHxBBApKqKoa8FqxuLh0yqgAxkYWDIhmKKgAFGAubjbFaACUVGBQhbAIJdS0DHRQpQBEThA9TeiNAGQjUD0Jg5xQYLXtwU1dvYzM08MAdP0AhFBjE8Js67NbZBDzDou08BDAyvDo7MoQcQLSUVI3dw9QdCaIL1w70y2TyDAsIgBhgAkkVWmhypVrCYaqh6lBIQhgIhZk0caiFgROt1toVUeVahcvIRgAALeDIADuRAgzIAovAGfBegBBRBQ-LoP4MQT3CAAGiGOWQpDAglu0Eg5nQyDUACsIHlZgyAG4MAAmEH1PVqr3ewKyuUFUAgAA8yHKIABGRFWdymeFowlLbpkz0UqlXaWoFDyjaCZBccqncgbVZsU1QAD0SagtgwWAAcsgbZzkPBJbSENA6SXwNBmgADVGVj4W0HWu0O+UAJldrmRHuVgcImJhcOVFNewdDEHDkej-TjPmAiZTaYzUGzua5heLUFLG-LeKg1c9tekQA)

Comment: Thanks, I had not thought of using a type guard. However if I do, it seems to suffer the same fate as `addPerson(completePartialPerson as Person)` in that it loses type safety unless I manually check all the fields like you have in the guard - in reality this is impractical due to the size of the object and the likelihood of modification. Updated: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-tvruwa?file=index.ts%3AL30

Comment: @wlf - You basically either relax type safety or check all the properties, I'm afraid. But we may be able to make it more automatic. Will you always have a `completePartialPerson` instance? (Or if not, can you arrange to have?) When I need to do things like this, I often have model objects that my type predicates / assertion functions can work from. (Usually the types are derived from the model objects as well, but that may not be possible in your case.)

Comment: Yes, I will always have a `completePartialPerson`. I thought about creating a utility type that removed all the `Partial`s, is this what you are suggesting? What would I then do with that type?

Comment: @wlf - If there aren't any union types in the properties of `Person`, you can implement `isPerson` by doing a recursive check of `p` against `completePartialPerson` to check that the types of the properties match (within a reasonable definition of "match" for this use case). (I'm assuming `completePartialPerson` is auto-generated along with the types.)